# jsDoc : Property 'xxxx' is not defined in type App.Signup.SignupCtrl

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, jsdoc

Im using jsDoc to comment all my code, and went through this warning that occurs on each of my properties. I have no idea how to define it, Im already commentating the most I can but I don't know what to do for these cases. Any help is appreciated !

[image: warning]

Comment: It doesn't matter so much, however if someone knows anything about that I would sleep better :D

Comment: issue is caused by `@type {App.Signup.SignupCtrl}` specified for `vm`; if you remove it, no errors will be shown

Comment: @lena hey, thanks for replying ! Ok, but since I need to bind these variables to my view, I need to attribute these to vm (or this). How could I do then? I can't get rid of it :/

Comment: can't suggest anything, sorry; please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27087 for updates

Comment: Oh well good enough ! thanks for the ticket :) @lena